# Yaw, Pitch and Roll to vectorDir and vectorUp

Tags: rotation, pitch, euler-angles

I have yaw, pitch and roll from an object and i need to transform it into vectorDir and vectorUp. Someone an idea of how to do it?

Comment: `roll` shouldn't contribute to direction, so draw your object on a piece of paper, mark the angles from the neutral/zero direction and have a look at how this turns into a circle. Then you should be able to figure it out. The `up` vector is a bit trickier.

Comment: thank you, ive got the solution for vectorDir! But im still working on the vectorUp :/

Comment: Yes, the question is indeed somewhat vague and incomplete but it can be answered (I did). Closing the question is enough, there is absolutely no need for the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert the Euler angles (yaw, pitch and roll) into a rotation matrix `M`. Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11956867/341970) for example.

It is not 100% clear what you need but you it is one of the followings.

You get vectorDir by multiplying the column vector `x=[1,0,0]` by either `M` or its transpose.

You get vectorUp by multiplying the column vector `z=[0,0,1]` by either `M` or its transpose.

**Note.** Euler angles are evil, they screw up the stability of your app, see for example

- [Strange behavior with android orientation sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5577334/341970),
- [Reducing wiimote pitch/roll variations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5010978/341970).

They are [not useful for interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580283/interpolating-between-rotation-matrices/5580491#5580491) either.